# Regex for user comments

Tags: regex

I need to use `regex` to accept only the following:

1. Numeric `(0-9)`
2. All alphabets (french, german, chinese)
3. Special characters `(@ #!()[]{}-_,.:;/`'"&*=+)`
4. All currency symbols.

Attempt `^[a-zA-Z0-9 @#,.!()}{][€£$]+$`

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a way to go:

```
^[\p{N}\p{L}\p{Sc}@ #!()\[\]{}\-_,.:;/'"&*=+]+$
```

Where:

```
\p{N}  : any digit
\p{L}  : any letter
\p{Sc} : any currency sign
```